# Help: Several errors per day for SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded;

Tags: magento-1.9, database, timeout

We're getting several errors per day.

This is received after it takes about 1 mins 10 seconds to 2 mins 25 seconds after clicking `Confirm Order`

I followed few suggestions but those RSS & observers changes did not help.

How can we resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: Already tried to restart MySQL? You have a table lock, restarting may help you fixing the problem if you have hanged processes

Comment: Yes. Had these issues thus also 2x upgraded the server config, but still getting these errors, few times a day. :(

Comment: You could try increasing the lock timeout value, but I think you should first investigate why you are getting locked. Any custom module?

Comment: True, but Nexcess hosting says, we can't change that. Yeah, I'm suspicious about the `Magestore Affiliate Plus` . Wrote to their support too, but also checking what else could be the issue.

Comment: I you have access to you MySQL you could try runing "SHOW FULLPROCESSLIST" to see if you have running tasks.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I see : http://i.imgur.com/a8O73N8.png
Is this currently stuck or this one is mandatory ?